# dompdf page break with codeigniter and foreach loop

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, dompdf, page-break

I am using codeigniter and dompdf to generate a pdf document.

the document is generated with a foreach loop. each loop creates a few table rows. I want to have a pagebreak between the rows of each loop.

my relevent codeigniter view syntax is:

```
<table width=100%>
<?php foreach($summary as $summary){  ?>
<tr class="firstrow">
<td colspan="10">
<?php echo  "<b>Customer</b>: <font color='blue'>".$summary->caccountname; ?>

<?php echo  "</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>Order Number</b>: <font color='blue'>".$summary->OrderNum; ?>

<?php echo  "</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>Sales rep</b>: <font color='blue'>".$summary->RepName; ?>

<?php echo  "</font>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <b>Due Date</b>: <font color='blue'>".substr($summary->DueDate,0,10); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="10"><hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="10">

  <table class="sortable" width="90%">
  <tr><td ><b>Product</td><td ><b>Ordered</td><td ><b>Processed</td><td ><b>Outstanding</td><td ><b>Dispatched</td><td ><b>Available (incl FJ)</td><td ><b>Available FJ</td></tr>
  <?php foreach($$linedetails as $linedetails){  ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Product;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->cubicvolume;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Processed;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Outstanding;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Dispatched;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->TotalVolume;  ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $linedetails->FJVolume;  ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>


<?php } ?>
</table>
```

I have given the first tr a class of `firstrow`, I would like a page break to appear before this line every time.

As such I have applied the following style sheet in my page header:

```
<style>
 @media print
 {
 .firstrow {page-break-before:always}
 }
</style>
```

This doesnt work.

How can I acheive my desired result of placeing a page break before each loop `firstrow` TR?

Thanks as always

Comment: Please explain what you want to do exactly, you want `<tr class='first_row'>` be on single pdf page? So every `..first_row..` will have own page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I am doing reports exactly same way

```
<?php 
$nbsp5 =  "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

foreach($summary as $summary) {  ?>
    <table width="100%" style="page-break-after:always;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">
                <?php echo  "<b>Customer</b>: <font color='blue'>".$summary->caccountname; ?>
                <?php echo  "</font>".$nbsp5 ." <b>Order Number</b>: <font color='blue'>".$summary->OrderNum; ?>
                <?php echo  "</font>".$nbsp5 ." <b>Sales rep</b>: <font color='blue'>".$summary->RepName; ?>
                <?php echo  "</font>".$nbsp5 ." <b>Due Date</b>: <font color='blue'>".substr($summary->DueDate,0,10); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10"><hr></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10">
              <table class="sortable" width="90%">
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Product</b></td>
                    <td><b>Ordered</b></td>
                    <td><b>Processed</b></td>
                    <td><b>Outstanding</b></td>
                    <td><b>Dispatched</b></td>
                    <td><b>Available (incl FJ)</b></td>
                    <td><b>Available FJ</b></td>
                </tr>
              <?php foreach($$linedetails as $linedetails){  ?>
              <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Product;  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->cubicvolume;  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Processed;  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Outstanding;  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->Dispatched;  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->TotalVolume;  ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $linedetails->FJVolume;  ?></td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

(first `<table>` tag moved inside loop)

Please try this answer for both [header and footer](http://goo.gl/IW6ZLz).

Comment: Thanks Kyslik, works 100%. any idea how to add a header with logo and footer? footer page 1 of 3. header just 'report'? else happy to do the research. Thanks again.

Comment: to add header, I would just include "new" table (inside each foreach iteration). As for pagination again add new table on the bottom. I will try to edit my answer but I do not know if it will work.

Answer (score 4):

To make Pagebreak work with `tr`, write a line of css for `tr`

```
 tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
```

Try above code.

If not working, then add

```
table { page-break-inside:auto }
```

Comment: Thanks, this didnt seem to have an effect on my pdf at all.

Comment: This worked well for me when using a div rather than a table!